# Custom class not found in a Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, class, laravel-5

I've had to try and work with an older package meant for php into my Laravel project.

I've added two custom classes, both are in the same folder "Classes" under the main "app" folder in my Laravel project.

One of these classes is recognized from a generated controller for my Laravel project. My paymentsController has `use App\Classes\Quickbooks_Payments;` in the top.

However, going to that Classes' file, I hit the following error through a route leading to my controller:

```
Class 'App\Classes\Quickbooks_Loader' not found
```

Now this is where this above is referenced in my paymentsController file:

```
<?php
namespace App\Classes\Quickbooks_Payments;

use App\Classes\Quickbooks_Loader;
/**
 * QuickBooks Payments class
 *
 */

/**
 * Utilities class (for masking and some other misc things)
 */
QuickBooks_Loader::load('/QuickBooks/Utilities.php');
```

This last line is where the above error is referenced. And I do have both the Quickbooks_Loader.php and the Quickbooks_Payments.php in the same folder. My Quickbooks_Loader.php file starts off as such:

```
<?php
namespace App\Classes\QuickBooks_Loader;
```

So I know this is likely because of my inexperience with custom/imported classes. What am I doing wrong and how should I properly "import" these custom classes and have them recognized without any issues?

Comment: The underscore in the class names is suspicious. It looks almost as though you're mixing PSR-0 and PSR-4 in the App namespace

Answer (score 0):

Change namespace in both classes you've shown to:

```
namespace App\Classes;
```

And run `composer du`

Also, make sure the class looks like this and not like you've shown (I'm not sure about did you cut something or not):

```
<?php
namespace App\Classes;

use App\Classes\Quickbooks_Loader;

class Quickbooks_Payments
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        dd('It\'s working!');
    }   
}
```